# Uniting two objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I have to shapes with anchor points perfectly aligned:

[image]

But the result is not what I want:

[image]

If I select the anchor points and try to join them, I get an error message because they are not open paths. When I use the pathfinder and click UNITE, nothing happens beside that those two shapes are grouped. Shape builder tool is not helpul either. Also, I don't want to expand these objects since I might want to change the stroke weight later on.

How can I join them perfectly so that the lower corner looks ok?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: expand them before Unite

Comment: Yes, but then I can't change the stroke width later when I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options for dealing with issues like this...

Change the corner type:

[image]

That works, but it changes your other corners too so probably not what you want.

Changing the end caps is a better option since it doesn't change the other corners. You can simply cut the problem corners with the Scissors Tool and set the end caps to round:

[image]

This is it with the end points separated so you can see how the paths are constructed:

[image]

The best option will depend on the specific shapes you're working with. You may just be able to construct your paths differently. This, for example, is a similar shape drawn as a single path (without changing any corner or cap options, so you still have the sharp corners):

[image]

Again, with the end points separated so you can see how it is constructed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily align this points:

- select anchor points you want to align
- open Align Panel (Shift+F7)
- press Horisontal Align Center then Vertical Align Center

To make shape from this separate lines you can group them (Ctrl+G) or make Compound Path (Ctrl+8)

Comment: Hi, as you can see from my 1st photo, the points are perfectly aligned. Using Pathfinder's options are not working which I also wrote about. Pressing Ctrl+8 does nothing.

Comment: I don't undestand you, if the points are perfectly aligned what you did that they become not aligned? 
And what shape do you want get from 4 open separate paths?

Comment: The accepted answer above explains what I was looking for.